# Некорректно выводится число с плавающей точкой

Tags: oracle, php

Всем, привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, почему выводятся нули? Поясню, пытаюсь вывести в таблицу значения из БД, однако, в таблицу получаю нули вместо тех значений которые хранятся в БД. Прикрепил скрины для лучшего понимания того, что происходит. Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: sprintf(), у вас в базе же число с плавающей точкой, естественно php выводит 0.0000 его как 0

Comment: sprintf() тоже не спас... (

Comment: @Артёмыч дайте результат

    var_dump($data['KOEF']);

Comment: @Sh4dow, string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "1" string(1) "1"

Comment: @Артёмыч вот это ад)

У вас в базе лежит "0.000012345", в `$data['KOEF']` приходит "1", а на сайте выводится "0"?

Лично мое мнение - 2 и 3 вместе быть не может. Но если вы там уже поколдовали с типами, то и выводить должно "1". Проверьте запрос - возможно, в нем есть приведение типов/округление. Теперь надо ждать кого-нибудь, кто шарит в оракле и скажет точнее)

Можете выложить пример запроса - шарящим в любом случае поможет.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй пустить число через функцию `round()` и во втором параметре укажи число 20 (то есть до скольки знаков после запятой округлять)

Comment: попробовал, не помогло :(

Comment: какой тип поля KOEF??

Comment: мне как то надо было записывать числа вида 000345559 (с нулями спереди и без точек) в БД. Так постоянно нули откидались и записывалось 345559. Стоял тип поля INT. Поменял на VARCHAR и все отлично заработало.

Comment: @mountpoint, ок спасибо, попробую узнать!

Comment: @mountpoint, сконвертили в CHAR - не помогло :(

Comment: может... VARCHAR, а не CHAR?

Comment: @mountpoint, попробовали и VARCHAR - без изменений

Answer (score 1):

[**number_format**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: @0xFFh, тоже не спасло, может настройки PHP?

Comment: Не спасло? Покажите, как вы его использовали?)

Answer (score 0):

Друзья! Проблема решена, всем спасибо за участие, дело в том что в функцию передаются ДАТА в формате mm-yyyy, а при неправильно дате выводятся нули, т.е. из кода в БД передавалась дата в неправильном формате mm.yyyy, а в БД запуск функции происходил с корректной датой. ВСЕМ СПАСИБО!